Abrir archivos directamente con vscode en Mac
tuve que reinstalar vs Code y no marqué la casilla de "habilitar abrir con Code" y ahora no puedo abrir los archivos directamente con el , alguien sabe si puedo cambiar esto desde la configuración o desde terminal? Gracias y un saludo.

No estoy seguro de que opción te refieres, es la del menú contextual? (click derecho -> abrir / abrir con) o cual?

¿Cuáles archivos no puedes abrir directamente?
